# Questions about my guitar's history

Tags: discussion, guitars, asking-questions

Would a question about my guitar's history be appropriate for this site?

I have found [several sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=fender+serial+number) that offer some partial information according to the serial number, but I was only able to get was the approximate manufacture date.

Would a question asking for more information be appropriate here?

Comment: What exactly would you like to know? Can you specify 'history'?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic - I'm not too sure TBH... The guitar was given to me 17 years ago and I was told that it was a sort of special edition because of the time and location of it's manufacturing... I've found that it was made in Japan between 1984-1987.

Comment: Something like [this](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/3910/1678)?

Comment: @AmericanLuke - Yep. I'll wait for the guitar to get back from it's setup so that I can include some pictures. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 7):

I think that a question like

> This is my guitar, when was it made, where etc [includes pics], please give me some info on its background story

is bound to be off topic, since it won't be any use to any future readers.

**But** a question like

> How can I find out more about my guitar's past? I have the serial number and it is in my possession for about 17 years. Is there a way to determine if my guitar is a 'special edition'?  etc etc

Is on topic here.

Comment: I see the distinction between the two and agree 100%. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Not marking yet as accepted - going to wait and see if more folks want to chime in :)

Comment: Other than the serial number, is there any other information that might be useful? Colors for example?

Comment: Colors might be of some use, but a guitar *can* be painted over. You should add brand name, model name, when you got it, where you got it from, when you think (or was informed) that it was manufactured and maybe what country it was manufactured in. These are all the things that could help i think

Comment: Well said, I agree.